# silex symfony doctrine ORM many to many: getRoles at login returns empty List

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine, roles, silex

Hello Silex (and Symfony) experts,

I need to implement a database authentification User/Role model via Doctrine  /ORM.

This is my silex composer setup:

```
"require": {
    "silex/web-profiler": "^2.0",
    "monolog/monolog": "1.13.*",
    "symfony/twig-bridge": "^3.2",
    "symfony/monolog-bridge": "^3.2",
    "symfony/console": "^3.2",
    "symfony/yaml": "^3.2",
    "symfony/security-bundle": "^3.2",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
    "dflydev/doctrine-orm-service-provider": "^2.0",
    "symfony/form": "^3.2",
    "symfony/validator": "^3.2",
    "symfony/config": "^3.2",
    "symfony/doctrine-bridge": "^3.2",
    "doctrine/migrations": "^1.5"
},
```

Users can register. Registered users can login and logout. Non registered visitors have anonymous role.

The symfony profiler is working, so I can see the security status (authentification/authoriszation). I also track the apache logfile for php errors.

I started from here https://github.com/fredjuvaux/silex-orm-user-provider (User from db, roles as array) and tried to expand it to  get user roles from database via doctrine many-to-many relation.

There are:

```
class MyUserController (different user actions like user,edit, register,... )
class MyUserManager implements UserProviderInterface (loadUserByUsername, ...)
class MyUserServiceProvider implements ServiceProviderInterface, ControllerProviderInterface,  BootableProviderInterface (controller routing and template setting)
```

The ORM entities are:

```
User:
/**
 * MyUser
 *
 * @Entity 
 * @Table(name="myuser")
 */
class MyUser implements UserInterface, \Serializable 
{
 ....

    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="MyRole", inversedBy="users")
     *
     */
     private $roles;

...
     * Constructor.
     *
     * @param string $email
     */
    public function __construct($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;
        $this->created = time();
        $this->salt = base_convert(sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)), 16, 36);
        $this->roles = new ArrayCollection();

    }

    ... 

      /**
     *
     * @return ArrayCollection list of the user's roles.
     */
    public function getRoles()
    {
      $result = $this->roles->toArray();   // throws error for login: 
      //  $result = $this->roles; // test   // thhrows error : null object
      dump($this->roles);
      //  $result = array("ROLE_USER", "ROLE_OTHER"); // static setting and 
works for login
      return $result;
    }
    ...
}


Roles (implements Roleinterface)
/**
 * MyRole
 * 
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="myrole")
 */
class MyRole implements RoleInterface
{

     /**
     * @var string
     * @Column(name="role", type="string", length=20, unique=true)
     */
    private $role;

    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="MyUser", mappedBy="roles")
     */
    private $users;

    ...
    /*
    *  methods for RoleInterface
    *  @return string|null A string representation of the role, or null
    */
    public function getRole()
    {
       $result = $this->role;
       return $result;
    }

}
```

When a user registers, he gets for that session the ROLE_USER role, 
authentification  and authorisation  are ok and a user is created in the 
database.

Then I can assign new roles ("role_test1", "role_test2") in the controller for the new user, the many-to-many table myuser_myrole is filled (myuser_id myrole_id).
When I change the roles, they are correctly updated by the entity manager.

When I access the user Entity from the userController to work on it, I can access the assigned roles:

```
// MyUserController.php
 $user = $em->getRepository('MyEntities\MyUser')->find($id);
 $roles= $user->getRoles()
 $role_length = count($roles);
 $role_list = array();
 for ($i=0; $i <$role_length ; $i++) 
 { 
      array_push($role_list,$roles[$i]->getRole());    // MyRole::getRole() prints out something to screen.
 }
 printf("<br> role-list:"); dump($role_list);
```

Calling this controller prints out the assigned roles via MyRole::getRole(), so ORM access works here.

**Now comes the strange:**

I want to login the new user with the login form.

When I use

```
// MyUser::getRoles() 
  return $this->roles;
```

It throws:

```
Argument 4 passed to Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Authentication\\Token\\UsernamePasswordToken::__construct() must be of the type array, object given,
```

Ok, makes maybe sense  because the $roles is an Doctrine ArrayCollection.

When I use

```
// MyUser::getRoles() 
  return $this->roles->toArray();
```

I can login with user password,but am not authenticated (yellow status). Dumping out the roles, I receive an empty array ArrayCollection.

```
roles:
ArrayCollection {#388 ▼
  -elements: []
}
```

The UsernamePasswordToken has an empty role-array.

```
When I use
// MyUser::getRoles() 
  return  array("ROLE_HELLO1", "ROLE_HELLO2");  // static role array with strings
```

I can login and am authenticated with these roles:

Roles

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => "ROLE_HELLO1"
  1 => "ROLE_HELLO2"
]
```

There are old docs about this (Managing Roles in the Database) for symfony 2 http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html, but it doesnt work in symfony3.

Here they use

```
   //class User
   public function getRoles()
    {
        return $this->groups->toArray();
    }

    //class Group extends Role (not RoleInterface, old?)
    public function getRole()
    {
        return $this->role;
    }
```

The actual symfony docs for user management do not show how to use roles stored in database.

**In summary:**

Login and user/role do not work as expected:

```
MyUser::getRoles()
```

- does not receive the Roles from database via doctrine ORM.
- has to return a string array of roles for login.
- delivers the correct role association in another controller.

**Questions:**

(1) Is this a Silex specific issue?

(2) How to use it correctly or where is a good link/doc for a workaround?

(3) Does the method LoadUserByUsername() interfere with all this?

(4) Do I need a class MyUserRepository extends EntityRepository {} to do the query and get the Role List?

(5) Do I need to use the Role Hierarchy service?

(6) Are there special naming conventions(tablename or class name) for "user" and "role"?

I found many posts asking the same/similar but they do not help here.

Thank you for help, I am really stuck on that!

dirk

Comment: There is an up to date article about [loading users from Database](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/entity_provider.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public function getRoles()
{
    return $this->roles->map(function (MyRole $role) {
        return $role->getRole();
    })->toArray();
}
```

You should also check if the relationship is correctly saved in database.
If there is **ManyToMany** relationship between *MyUser* and *MyRole*, you have to ensure that relationship is saved in both entities.

```
//class MyUser
public function addRole(MyRole $role)
{
    $this-roles->add($role);
    $role->users->add($user);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I tried both suggestions. But no change, Array returned from getRoles() remains empty. I think the relationship is correct, because from the MyUser controller (outside the entity class) I can acces the roles. It is MyUser::getRoles() inside the entity while the login action, which makes the problem. Maybe I can access the entitymanager from somewhere else while login?

Comment: Have you checked in database tables is everything really correct? You can also try to check if ManyToOne relationship will work.

Comment: I tried the Many to one relation   
/**
* @ManyToOne(targetEntity="MyRole")
*/
private $roles;

If I use in MyUser.php:

    public function getRoles()
    {
        $result = array($this->roles->getRole());
      return $result;
    }

I get the correct Role at login, but this is just a single role.

Comment: Have you read my answer, section about saving ManyToMany relationships?

Answer (score 0):

I had a break on this, but now it seems to work. Thank you miikes for the addRole() suggestion!

finally I have: MyUser.php:

```
//Myuser.php
/**
 * MyUser
 *
 * @Entity 
 * @Table(name="myuser")
 */

class MyUser implements UserInterface,  \Serializable //, ObjectManagerAware
{
    ...

    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="MyRole", inversedBy="users")
     */
    private $roles;

    public function __construct($email)
    {
    (...)
    $this->roles = new ArrayCollection();


     /**
     *
     * @return ArrayCollection list of the user's roles.
     */
    public function getRoles()
    {   
       $result = $this->roles->toArray();
       return $result;
    }

    public function assignToRole($role)
    {
        $this->roles[] = $role;
    }

    public function setRole($myrole)
    {   
    $this->roles= $myrole;
    }

    public function hasRole($role)
    {
        return in_array(strtoupper($role), $this->getRoles(), true);
    }

        public function addRole(MyRole $role)
    {
      $this->roles->add($role);
      //$role->users->addRole($this); // could not access roles->user->...  
                      // because private variable in MyRole but it works 
    }

        /**
     * Remove the given role from the user.
     *
     * @param string $role
     */
    public function removeRole($role)
    {   
      dump($role);
      $this->roles->removeElement($role);
    }

    (...) // other setters getters

    public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize(array(
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->password,
            $this->salt, 
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @see \Serializable::unserialize()
     */
    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        list (
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->password,
            $this->salt,
            ) = unserialize($serialized);
    }
}
```

and MyRole.php:

```
// MyRole.php

/**
 * MyRole
 * 
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="myrole")
 */
class MyRole implements RoleInterface
{
    (...)

    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="MyUser", mappedBy="roles")
     */
    private $users;


     /**
     * @var string
     * @Column(name="role", type="string", length=20, unique=true)
     */
    private $role;


    /*
    *  methods for RoleInterface
    *  @return string|null A string representation of the role, or null
    */
    public function getRole()
    {
       $result = $this->role;
       return ($result);
    }

    public function setRole($role)
    {
        $this->role= $role;
        return $this;
    }

    (...)

     /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->users = new ArrayCollection();
    }

     /**
     * Add user
     * @param \MyEntities\MyUser $user
     * @return MyRole
     */
    public function addUser($user)
    {
        $this->users[] = $user;
        return $this;
    }


    public function setUser($user)
    {
        $this->users[] = $user;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove user
     *
     * @param \MyEntities\MyUser $user
     */
    public function removeUser($user)
    {
        $this->users->removeElement($user);
    }

    /**
     * Get users
     *
     * @return ArrayCollection $users
     */
    public function getUsers()
    {
        return $this->users;
    }

     /**
     * __toString()
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->bezeichnung;
    }
}
```

With the help of the doctrine orm commands

```
vendor/bin/doctrine  orm:validate-schema
vendor/bin/doctrine  orm:schema-tool:update  --dump-sql
```

the correct manyToMany table **myuser_myrole** was generated and the role setting works at login of a user.

I think, the most important was the correct use of the function addRole() (with this->roles->add($role), and not something like this->roles->addRole($role) ) to let doctrine do the magic stuff in the background.

Thanks for any help and comments!
dirk